# How to push additional routes from backend API on app initizalzation

Tags: angular, api, angular-ui-router

I am writing something similiar to CMS. I have two apps. Backend written in Django and a SPA in angular 7. I the backend part I have views that that `list-pages` and `retrieve-page`

On sending request to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/pages-management/pages` returns `json` with data:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "some title 1",
    "section": "section1",
    "urlKey": "some_title_1"
  },
    {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "some title 2",
    "section": "section2",
    "urlKey": "some_title_2"
  },
]
```

On sendint request to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/pages-management/pages/some_title_1
```

It returns:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "some_title_1",
  "section": "section1",
  "urlKey": "some_title_1",
  "content": "<p>html content</p>"
}
```

What I want to achieve?

I would like to be to load data from `/pages-management/pages` on angular app start and the data to create routes from it.

In the first attempt I tried to add those routes during my header component initialization:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  currentUserEmail: string;
  pages: Page[];

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private pageService: PageService, private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // TODO remove the property this.authService.currentUserEmail and export currentUserEmail from localstorage?
    this.currentUserEmail = this.authService.currentUserEmail;

    this.pageService.getPages().subscribe(data => {
      this.pages = data;
      const data = this.router.config.filter(value => value.path === 'children')[0].children;
      this.pages.forEach(item => {
        data.push({path: item.urlKey, component: PageComponent});
      });
    }, error1 => {
    });
  }
} 

  <div class="nav-item mr-2">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
              <button class="btn btn-light" id="studentZoneDropDown" ngbDropdownToggle>
                Strefa Studenta
              </button>
              <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
                <button class="dropdown-item" [routerLink]="['strefa-studenta', page.urlKey]"
                        *ngFor="let page of pages">{{page.title}}</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

It almost works when I let the app to load and enter the url through link in my navigation bar. The problem is when I try directly to enter the url through browser link `http://localhost:4200/children/some_title_1` It dosent work. But navigating from `http://localhost:4200` to `http://localhost:4200/children/some_title_1` through link in the navbar is possible.

The question is how to achieve this goal?

Comment: Im guessing this is because that route does not exist yet - you could try loading in APP_INITIALIZER.
https://long2know.com/2017/11/angular-dynamic-routes-and-application-initialization/

Comment: @RichardFriend It was very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to perform data loading when your application startup, you can use the `APP_INITIALIZER` injection token:

```
@NgModule({
   ...
   providers: [
      {
          provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
          useFactory: initializeApplication,
          deps: [/* Add dependencies here */],
          multi: true
      }
   ]
})
export class AppModule {}

export function initializeApplication(/* Inject dependencies here */) {
    return () => {
        // TODO: send http request or execute promises.
    };
}
```

Find more informations here: https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-how-to-use-app-initializer/

Hope it helps.